# tabBarController is nil; can't change selectedIndex on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController like this:

```
/*SomeTabBarController.h*/
@interface SomeTabBarController: UITabBarController
@end
```

and in the *SomeTabBarController.m* i want to change the active tab on viewDidLoad

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
}
```

However, tabBarController is *nil*.
What am i missing?
I have a navigation controller and segue push to the tab bar controller...

Thx

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.selectedIndex = 1;
```

**You** are the tabBarController :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a property of an item that doesn't exist yet :) try changing the selected tab in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Or if you are able to create your tab controller in code on viewDidLoad, then you could simply set selected index on the next line.

Comment: the *self.tabBarController* is *nil* in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear too. And that is exactly what i am wondering about. Did i miss some binding or initialization what causes the *tabBarController* to be nil? Changing the *selectedIndex* in the *viewDidLoad* should work; at least i found some examples recommending this way to change the tab.

Comment: @matthias If you don't try to manually set the selected index what happens? Does it still crash?

Comment: its not crashing at all. it just doesn't open the second tab but still behaves like default and opens the first tab.